# Less is not finding first child selector

Tags: css-selectors, less

I wrote this code in a less file:

```
.page-cartPage .jc-banner .row-height > .col-xs-12:first-child {
display: none; }
```

But I don't see the right behaviour. 
Is this written right for less?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pure CSS, what you can do is, trying to take the parent div of the div you want to display:none then make like my example:

```
.myparent .col-xs-12:first-child{
     display:none;
}
```

I hope I helped you.